# Ruby 1.8.7: Can't load module from custom gem

Tags: ruby, import, module, rubygems

After creating a custom gem I'd like to reference functions defined in a module it contains.

Custom gem is `dsi_core` and the module `lib/cuke.rb` contains simply:

```
module DsiCore
    module Cuke
        def self.Features(*args)
            puts "Hello world!"
        end
    end
end
```

I've installed the gem and can see `/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/dsi_core-0.1.0/lib/cuke.rb` exists as it should.

In another gem `dsi_fabric` there is the code `dsi_fabric/lib/dsi_fabric`:

```
require 'dsi_core'
# ...
DsiCore::Cuke.Features(*ARGV)
```

Trying to run this from the `lib/` directory of `dsi_fabric` gem:

```
ruby -rubygems ./dsi_fabric.rb arg1 arg2
```

..results in:

```
./dsi_fabric.rb:7: uninitialized constant DsiCore::Cuke (NameError)
```

This refers to the `Cuke.Features` line in `dsi_fabric.rb`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you added in `gemspec` file? And in it `gem.require_paths = ["lib"]`, also can you build gem than try it.

Comment: @Dolphin Yes all files in the project are referenced in the `gemspec` for `dsi_core`. Also the `require_paths` is set as you specify.

Comment: Well ... you should write `def self.Features(*args)` but that is not the reason for that error.

Comment: @Dolphin I've tried swapping my `def Features... module_function` with simply `def self.Features` but it hasn't had any effect sadly. I believe those two are equivalent so either should work. Have updated my post anyway.

Comment: You are on the right track it cannot see `Cuke` class, I am saying if you want to use it way you do in the example you need `self.`

Answer (score 1):

You're requiring 'dsi_core' instead of 'cuke'. Try changing `require 'dsi_core'` to `require 'cuke'`.

Comment: As explained above `dsi_core` is the name of the first gem which is built, then the second gem in development `dsi_fabric` should reference it to access the `Cuke` module.

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing in existing namespace problem can be namespace, so try with root namespace reference.

```
::DsiCore::Cuke.Features(*ARGS)
```

also like I mentioned in comment you need to put

```
def self.Features(*args)
  # ...
end
```

Hehe I do not like that capital method name annotation but to each his own :)

**EDIT**

Also try

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'dsi_core'
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, Dolphin. I've tried `::DsiCore` but receive the same error: `./dsi_fabric.rb:7: uninitialized constant DsiCore::Cuke (NameError)`

Comment: @KomodoDave are you missing `require 'rubygems'`? I will edit my answer.

Comment: The command I said I'm running begins with `ruby -rubygems` - shouldn't this achieve the same effect? EDIT: Yes I've confirmed it has the same effect - removing `-rubygems` gives me a `no such file to load -- dsi-core` so it can see the gem when I pass that parameter to `ruby`.

Comment: Thanks for your help Dolphin - I've just figured it out, see my new Answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was miscomprehending how Gem imports work.

If you create a gem and add other gem dependencies to it in the gemspec, those dependencies are automagically imported already.

Therefore what I have above is wrong - to import the `cuke.rb` file from gem `dsi_core` in gem `dsi_fabric` you would use:

```
require 'cuke'
```

i.e. the `require dsi_core` is implicit by nature of the Gem specification and gemspec.

Then to reference in the code would be

```
DsiCore::Cuke
```

..as I originally posted.

I was confused because mny public gems indicate you should use `require` with the form:

```
require `gem-name/module-or-class`.
```

However this is misleading: the gem name isn't being used at all, but rather a directory named after the gem:

```
require 'dir-name/module-or-class'
```

In this example the gem `gem-name` has the following directory structure:

```
lib/gem-name/module-or-class.rb
```

i.e. they've made a folder in the gem's `lib/` directory named after the gem itself.

Comment: hmmm strange, shouldn't be just first require? I will keep that in mind, good luck.

Comment: I've amended my answer - what I showed originally did work but was incorrect. See expanded explanation above.